# Can not add .NET framework 4.6.2 web app reference to .NET Standard any version

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-standard

I have created a .NET framework 4.6.2 web application.

Then I have created a .NET Standard class library. The target framework is 1.6 or 1.5 or everything lower it does not matter.

When I add the web application as project reference to the .NET Standard class library (unit test project) I get this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       One or more projects are incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.5.               
Error       Project Api is not compatible with netstandard1.5 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.5). Project Api supports: net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2)
```

I use Visual Studio 2017 and have latest .NET Core 1.0/11 SDK installed.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Microsoft clearly knows the .NET Standard projects should not use any non-.NET Standard libraries/projects as references. What are you looking for exactly? Do you really know what is .NET Standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current 1.0 tooling .NET 4.6.2 can reference a .NET Standard 1.5 project, but a .NET Standard 1.5 project can not reference a .NET 4.6.2 project.

Once the "Tooling 2.0" comes out with netstandard 2.0 you will be able to do both directions using the [new shims feature](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/netstandard-20/README.md#assembly-unification), but until that comes out you will need to make your class library unit test project also a .NET 4.6.2 project.

Comment: That was my half... solution too, but I need to add some nugets Microsoft.AspNetCore.* to my NetStandard class library, because they do not work with NET462 HAHAHA.... Does Microsoft actually know what they do?

Comment: Yes, that is why they are releasing tooling 2.0 to fix all this.

Comment: @Pascal: Even with 2.0 tooling you won't make yourself a favor by referencing most of the .NET >=4.5 dlls this way. Unless you are **120% certain** that the referenced DLL only use netstandard1.6 (or 2.0) API, it will be a ".NET Framework" solution and explode when run on .NET Core (either windows or linux) at runtime and gives people a wrong impression that it's crossplatform because "library A targets netstandard", but references a ".net 4.5 dll which uses API which are not available in .NET Standard"

Comment: But what is the point to allow reference full .NET dll from .NET standard?

Comment: @Tseng so my goal should be then for now to create a .NET Core web app with class library STandard 2.0 preview ?

Comment: @Pascal: Can't tell you. For one, we don't know why you need to use .NET 4.6 for the web app instead of .NET Core. Second we don't know if the APIs are/will be part of netstandard 2.0. Install VS(2017) 15.3 preview (maybe works with 15.2 too) and install [.NET Portability Analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ConnieYau.NETPortabilityAnalyzer), run it and analyze the 4.6.2 assemblies you need with it `netstandard 2.0` profile and see if it contains Apis which are not in netstandard 2.0 yet